# Conversion of Money attributes using update_attributeS for money gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

Please consider  two objects of class Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base {
  :id => :integer,
  :name => :string,
  :total_stock => :integer,
  :cents_retail_sale_amount => :integer,
  :cents_cost_amount => :integer,
  :created_at => :datetime,
  :updated_at => :datetime
}
```

Let's say I have 2 objects:

```
  a{
  :id => 12,
  :name => "Shirt",
  :total_stock => 1,
  :cents_retail_sale_amount => 2500,
  :cents_cost_amount => 2100,
  :created_at => Mon, 23 Jul 2012 16:16:33 CDT -05:00,
  :updated_at => Mon, 23 Jul 2012 17:24:15 CDT -05:00}

  b {
  :id => nil,
  :name => "Polo Shirt",
  :total_stock => 1,
  :cents_retail_sale_amount => 2500,
  :cents_cost_amount => 2100,
  :created_at => Mon, 23 Jul 2012 16:16:33 CDT -05:00,
  :updated_at => Mon, 23 Jul 2012 17:24:15 CDT -05:00}
```

Now here is what I'm trying to do:

```
a.update_attributes(b.to_product.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at")
```

The problem however ( which I caught only cause I have a validation on the cents fields - to allow amounts only between 0 and $100 ( 10000 cents)), is this - my cents fields get also updated and get extra 00 at the end - so I get $2500 & $2100 for the the retail and cost amounts. While really nice profit margin - not really realistic.

I can obviously do some kind of processing on the b object before updating attributes ( such as not updating money fields and do the separately one by one), but that's not really efficient. So I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails gem instead which solved the issue